# Is there anyway to get database of non debuggable android application on non-rooted device with adb?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, adb

I need to get my android application database with usb connection on non-rooted device and I want to use adb commands. 
I've used ==> "adb exec-out run-as mypackagename cat /databases/mydbname.db > myPCaddress(D:\mydbname.db)" not working and for adb pull I don't have permission.

Comment: I've tested ==> "adb pull -h /data/data/mypackagename/databases/mydbname.db /sdcard/somdirectory/mydbname.db" and I get "adb: unrecognized option '-h'"

Comment: so remove `-h` option: more http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-pull

Comment: adb pull (without -h) for pulling to sdcard ==>No such file or directory and for pulling to my PC ==>  remote Permission denied

Answer (score -2):

So one of the solutions is to copy the database out of the `data` directory to some other location, let's say an sd card.

1) Create a folder in an accessible place that you will copy the database to: `mkdir /sdcard/data/`
2) `run-as <com.your.package>` (which will lead you to your package's `data` directory, or you can just use `cd` to navigate there I think)
3) `cp databases/<database>.db /sdcard/data/` (copy the database file)
4) `exit` all the way out

And once you copied the file you can either navigate there (to `/sdcard/data/`) and use `sqlite3` to navigate through it. Or you can use `adb pull` because it's in an accessible location. You can find the source at [this](https://www.liammoat.com/blog/2017/pull-an-sqlite-database-file-from-an-android-device-for-debugging).

Comment: I can't navigate to my package because my device is not rooted and I get ==> run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted

Comment: @user3323136 it's not because the device is not rooted, I did it with my Samsung S8, and it's not rooted. I believe it's a bug. Can you try using `cd` to navigate, like `cd data/data/databases`?

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote? This method works for a non-rooted device, I tested it myself. But there exists a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37093233#comment53) with some Samsung devices with `run-as`.

Comment: It doesn't work because if you try this on a release package without debuggable=true, it will say you can't access a non debuggable package (which makes sense). Like if you download an app from the play store you can't access the data inside

Comment: I can't navigate to my package because  adb gives me this run-as: package not debuggable: <com.name.package>.